# Group_Concat wont work

Tags: php, mysql

When I try this code on phpmyadmin it works

```
$results=mysqli_query($db,"
SELECT a.id
     , f.titulli
     , f.cmimi
     , GROUP_CONCAT( Concat(x.emri,x.mbiemri ) SEPARATOR "," ) AS Aktori
  FROM aktfil a
  JOIN filmat f
    ON a.id=f.id 
  JOIN aktoret x
    ON a.idakt=x.idakt
 GROUP 
    BY f.titulli") or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

But when I write on.php it says this 
*Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab\betterdisplay\serverbetterdisplay.php on line 10*

Comment: You need to escape or use different quotes inside your query than the ones that enclose it; try `','` instead of `","`. You're calling `mysqli_query(a, b, c) or die...`, not `mysqli_query(a,b) or die...`.

Comment: Are you working with [m_lat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9174846/m-lat)? He has a similar query using the same tables.

Answer (score 1):

The right code thanks to @Uueerdo

```
$results=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT aktfil.id, filmat.titulli, filmat.cmimi, 
GROUP_CONCAT( Concat( aktoret.emri,aktoret.mbiemri ) SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Aktori 
FROM aktfil JOIN filmat ON aktfil.id=filmat.id JOIN aktoret ON aktfil.idakt=aktoret.idakt
GROUP BY filmat.titulli") or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Comment: Please accept your answer and modify your original question to include php code you initially experienced trouble with, if possible.